# React w/ Rails API, sudden proxy error?! ECONNRESET Proxy error: Could not proxy request from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, proxy, localhost, foreman

Thanks in advance for any insight -- I am having a heck of a time tracing this one. Error seemed to come out of nowhere.

I built a React/Rails app using the `foreman` gem, following this article https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-get-create-react-app-to-work-with-your-rails-api/

`package.json` contains these lines for the proxy:

```
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
```

And I boot up client and server simultaneously using `foreman`, with this `Procfile`:

```
web: cd client && npm start
api: bundle exec rails s -p 3001
```

This has all been working FINE for days now... it worked the last time I opened it... and now this error appears out of nowhere and is driving me nuts!

I've checked and the port is not in use (`sudo lsof -i :3001` with no result)

I've backed up to a previous `commit`, I've trashed and re-cloned...

**Why would this error suddenly appear?** Nothing relevant has been changed. It worked, I went to sleep, I woke up, it doesn't work.

Thanks again for any advice.

Comment: Could you try deleting `node_modules` and installing your dependencies again?

Comment: Also can you post the actual error message? (Unless I'm missing something)

Comment: thanks @KenoClayton -- same error -- the error message is in the title... it's an error in the Terminal... the `fetch` request remains pending in the browser and never complete... that's the unwanted behavior, though there is no error message in browser

Comment: It sounds like your server at `:3001` isn't starting yet. Double check the steps and see if there's something you missed.

Comment: Thanks again @KenoClayton Server is running. Same errors happen even if I boot up client and server separately rather than simultaneously with Foreman.  It was literally working last night and suddenly doesn't up on boot this morning - I haven't changed a thing. Really stumped.

Comment: It's possible that there could be a conflict somewhere, perhaps if the clients weren't closed properly. Have you tried rebooting just to rule that out?

Comment: Yeah, tried rebooting, even tried cloning the repo on a new machine and encountered the same error. Really brain twister, this one. I'm sure it will turn out to be something trivial and "obvious" in hind sight, but atm i'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. Also try making sure the dependencies are up to date. It does seem odd that it would not work seemingly out of nowhere, while nothing has changed. Also, does your error have any additional info in it? (e.g. ECONNRESET or similar)

Comment: Yes, ECONNRESET (see title for full error)... I think I have working for now. I stopped using Foreman and just boot server/client separately. I suspect `bootstrap` was maybe causing some kind of caching error that was taking my Rails server offline... not sure, but for now it feels duct-taped together enough to continue. Cheers.